# Set Android app version using Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to use Gradle to set app's name. Please, look at this snippet of build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionCode getVersionCode()
        versionName getVersionName()
        ...
    }
    ...
}

...

int getVersionCode() {
    return 1
}

def getVersionName() {
    return "1.0"
}
```

Android Studio says

```
   'versionCode' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Integer'
   'versionName' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String'
```

and when I install the app on a device it has no versionCode and versionName at all.

The problem is clear to me but I don't know how to solve it.
Please advice.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**EDITED**

In order to define your app version dynamically, specify a custom method with def and call it, as such:

```
def computeVersionName() {
    return "2.0"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 12
        versionName computeVersionName()
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

See [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basic-Build-Customization) for more.

Make sure not to use function names that could conflict with existing getters in the given scope. For instance, `defaultConfig { ... }` calling `getVersionName()` will automatically use the getter `defaultConfig.getVersionName()` instead of the custom method.

Comment: Thank you for response. I also need to use versionCode and versionName values in other places of build.gradle. If I hardcode it like this I won't be able to do that. Therefore I use methods.

Comment: Does putting your `def` method ahead of the `android` bracket do anything?

Comment: unfortunatelly it doesn't.

Comment: The link does mention
`Note: Do not use function names that could conflict with existing getters in the given scope. For instance instance defaultConfig { ...} calling getVersionName() will automatically use the getter of defaultConfig.getVersionName() instead of the custom method.`

So try a different method name.

Comment: I have a function named `getMinSdkVersion()` and it does not work, if I rename it to `getMinSdk()` it works... does that means the previous function name is predefined somewhere?

Comment: Exactly. We don't know exactly what those predefined function names are, so just in case a method name doesn't work in your own gradle configuration try out a different one.

Answer (score 51):

It doesn't resolve your issue, but it can be a different solution.

You can use gradle.properties inside your root project and define:

```
VERSION_NAME=1.2.1
VERSION_CODE=26
```

Then in your build.gradle you can use:

```
versionName project.VERSION_NAME
versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
```

Comment: Note: This worked great till updating to use newer build tools! I noticed afterwards, that my version code was unset and Integer.parseInt is marked in Android Studio as unknown. Now this is needed:  **project.VERSION_CODE.toInteger()**

Comment: The asker is probably looking for a dynamically set solution.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a build.gradle that I am using based on ideas from [JakeWharton](https://plus.google.com/+JakeWharton/posts/6f5TcVPRZij) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
def versionMajor = 1
def versionMinor = 2
def versionPatch = 0

def gitVersion() {
    def counter = 0
    def process = "git rev-list master --first-parent --count".execute()
    return process.text.toInteger()
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'my.project.com'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode gitVersion()
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Hey Phileo99 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556005/git-rev-list-not-working-in-android-studio-build-gradle

Answer (score 1):

First of all - you are calling **the inner getter.**, hence you have nulls.

**versionCode** property is accessed by **getVersionCode()**.

**versionName** property is accessed by getVersionName()

So you get null and assign null... - remember, you are inside `defaultConfig` scope, hence Gradle will use the closest `gerVersionCode()` function.

There is a cleaner way to make it in newer Android Gradle (4.1.2).

Usually, those values are separated to the new file.

Firstly, you should use `closures`, not `functions`.

Fuction:

```
def myFunction() {

}
```

Closure:

```
myClosure = {

}
```

Also, you can extend `ext` scope (it is used to store all custom project-wide Gradle properties, this is a great place for it!) with your closure!

Remember not to name your functions 'getVersionName' 'getVersionCode'

Create a file `config.gradle`:

```
ext {
    appSetup = [
            majorVersion     : 1,
            minorVersion     : 0,
            patchVersion     : 0
    ]

    getAppVersionCode = { appSetup.majorVersion * 10000 + appSetup.minorVersion * 100 + appSetup.patchVersion }

    getAppVersionName = { "${appSetup.majorVersion}.${appSetup.minorVersion}.${appSetup.patchVersion}" }
```

In `build.gradle`:

```
// applies bloc
apply from: 'config.gradle'

android {
    versionCode getAppVersionCode()
    versionName getAppVersionName()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `gradle.properties` file to store shared build versions, make sur to use the `toInteger()` function for the version code, compiled/min and target sd versions.

See this post for more information: https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/gradle-configure-variables-for-all-android-project-modules-in-one-place-5a6e56cd384e#.yl1x0ziqe