# Git rev-list not working in Android Studio build.gradle

Tags: android, git, github, gradle

I've setup my Android Studio Project to work with Github. Here is my Manifext

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


def gitVersion() {
    def counter = 0
    def process = "git rev-list master --first-parent --count".execute()
    counter = process.text.toInteger()
    return counter
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    def versionMajor = 0
    def versionMinor = 1
    def versionPatch = 0

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.packagename"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode gitVersion()
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I use gitVersion() I get the following error,

```
Error:(7, 0) For input string: ""
```

To me, this means that process is being returned an empty string. However, I am able to run this from my command line and get the expected result.

Why is this happening just in Android Studio?

Comment: In my repo this code works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. Android studio performs command line operations in the project folder by default. I had made my project such that the git repo lived inside my app directory instead of in my project directory, so any git commands on the project level would error, since it didn't know about the git repo one directory down.

My solution was to **move my git repo out of the app directory and into the project directory**. Once I did that, the script worked perfectly.

Comment: Is there any workaround if you don't want to move the git repo?

Comment: Not that i know. I discovered that it is, in fact, extremely poor practice to include your git repo otherwise. You should start including your get repo in your project directory from now on.

Comment: I guess I'll do that. Thanks :)

Comment: @nadavfima you should take look at git pull origin's answer

Answer (score 4):

Just specify the working directory for `execute()`:

```
.execute([], project.rootDir)
```

Comment: This is the one, so you can just simply execute for the current commit hash:
def cmdgithash = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'
def gitHash = cmdgithash.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()

Answer (score 1):

I wrote and tested that script for use on OSX Mavericks.  What kind of OS platform are you using to make your build?  Also, have you tried it without the ".text" ?  You may have to play around with different combinations on that line to see what will work.

Answer (score 0):

This method will help you get your revision number:

```
int extractVersionCode() {
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        workingDir projectDir
        executable 'git'
        args 'rev-list', '--count', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim().toInteger()
}
```

Usage:

```
versionCode extractVersionCode()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def gitCommitCount = Integer.parseInt(['sh', '-c', 'git rev-list HEAD | wc -l | tr -d " "'].execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim())

defaultConfig {
  ...
  versionCode gitCommitCount
  ...
}
```