# Set versionCode from last git tag

Tags: android, git, gradle

I'm trying to make Gradle pick up the last tag from Git and use it as `versionName`. I defined this simple task:

```
def gitTag() {
    def cmd = "git describe --abbrev=0 --tags"
    def proc = cmd.execute()
    return  proc.text.trim()      
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    // (...)  
    versionName gitTag() ?: "NO_VERSION"
}
```

The problem is that this only works as expected when building from the command line. When I try to run the app from Android Studio, I always get "NO_VERSION".

**EDIT:** After some tests it seems that it is failing because the working directory when running Android Studio is `~/.AndroidStudio/system/compile-server`, so the command above fails because that directory is not a git repository.

**EDIT2:** After playing around some more, it seems that only some commands fail. If I replace the command with `git --version` or `git status` I get the expected output, but if I use something like `git rev-list HEAD --count` both stdout and stderr are empty. Using `git rev-list HEAD` will work as well. WAT

So how can I execute the git command using the Gradle project dir as working dir?

Comment: Have you tried with the full path to the git command line?

Comment: @Quanturium Yes and the result is the same. The problem seems to be realted to the working directory used.

Comment: What is the output of the command?

Comment: This seems to be the same problem as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556005/git-rev-list-not-working-in-android-studio-build-gradle

Comment: Try `cd /path/to/working/directory && git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`.

Comment: @Quanturium Thanks for your suggestion. Indeed that was one of the problems, but still it does not work. See my edit

Comment: @Salem What is your problem now?